# "Joining?" on distinct values in row and then match

Tags: r

Apologies for the awful title, not sure how to describe my question.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
----------------------------------
| media_id | filename | duration |
----------------------------------
|  782363  | 000041f1 |   12577  |
----------------------------------
|  782379  | 000041f1 |   12570  |
----------------------------------
|  1449109 | 00006c9b |  530423  |
----------------------------------
|  1449160 | 00006c9b |  530420  |
----------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is match the unique filenames (there will only ever be a maximum of two rows that match) like so:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| media_id | filename | duration | filename2 | duration2 |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  782363  | 000041f1 |   12577  | 000041f1  |   12570   |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1449109 | 00006c9b |  530423  | 00006c9b  |  530420   |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

The purpose is to compute the absolute difference between the duration and duration 2.  For context, the original filenames have distinct file extensions, but I have truncated them because that is how I need to match the durations.  I'm trying to see if the duration of fileA is different than fileB after is has been converted from one format to the other.

I'm familiar with dplyr but the best algorithm I could come up with was

```
1-Identify the unique filenames
2-Search through the filename column using grep to locate the rows where the filenames are located
3-Somehow transform, or create a new data frame, that matches the filenames.
```

Any ideas/suggestions?  The dataset will have around 1 million rows so ideally I need something that is fairly performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to reshape as well

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_frame(
  media_id = c(782363, 782379, 1449109, 1449160),
  filename = c("000041f1", "000041f1", "00006c9b", "00006c9b"),
  duration = c(12577, 12570, 530423, 530420) ) %>%
    group_by(filename) %>%
    mutate(sub_group = 1:n()) %>%
    gather(variable, value, -filename, -sub_group) %>%
    unite(new_variable, variable, sub_group) %>%
    spread(new_variable, value) %>%
    mutate(duration.difference = duration_1 - duration_2)
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution and R keeps crashing.  My guess is a memory limitation.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Well certainly try on a small subset of data first to get out any bugs. But you'd probably want to turn to data.table if you really want to speed things up. A bunch of people on here are data.table wizards but not me

Answer (score 0):

Another option outside of `dplyr` would be to use `reshape2`'s `dcast`.  It's essentially an unmelt/pivot function.

```
library(reshpape2)
df <- data.frame(
  media_id = c(782363, 782379, 1449109, 1449160),
  filename = c("000041f1", "000041f1", "00006c9b", "00006c9b"),
  duration = c(12577, 12570, 530423, 530420))

# Identify a file sequence (will be different with larger distributed file).  
# Will work if file is sorted by filename and has exactly two records per filename.
df$file_seq <- paste('d', rep(1:2), sep='')

# unmelt
df2 <- dcast(data = df, formula = filename ~ file_seq, value.var = 'duration')

# calculate the difference
df2$diff <- abs(df2$d1 - df2$d2)
```

Getting R to work on a larger scale is a different challenge but I believe this is a fairly simple solution.  Good luck.